# Lock oracle table from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle10g

I have a view defined in SQL Server 2008 R2 and that view "is looking" a table in Oracle 10g using linked server.

I need to do this (using a SqlServer-side Store Procedure):

1. get a numerator from the view.
2. do some things affecting SQL Server tables.
3. update the numerator in the view.

This takes a small time, but I want to lock the oracle table during all my process because other programs may use the table.
So, what I want to do is:

1. lock the oracle table
2. get a numerator from the view.
3. do some things affecting SQL Server tables.
4. update the numerator in the view.
5. release the lock

Don't know how to do steps 1 and 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I´m sorry, my mistake. It´s a numeric field that gives the last number assigned to anything (like... the last client number). So you can add the next client using that number + 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following in oracle:

```
create materialized view foo_View  
as  
--select statement that has the data sql server is looking for
```

then perform a scheduler task, also in Oracle, that rebuilds/ refreshes this view on an interval.

There is no need for SQL Server to dictate anything to Oracle, it sounds like the application is bleeding over where it shouldn't be.  The benefit of the Oracle materialized view is that it can be queried without causing Oracle to shut down while this SQL Server process is running.

**FROM THE COMMENTS**

> My process runs on SQL Server, but I need to lock the Oracle table.

This is why I suggested using the materialized view.  You won't care if another process modifies the underlying table as the only data that SQL Server will be able to access is that snapshot (aka the materialized view).  So you won't have to worry about any contention of resources / mid stream updates that could corrupt the SQL Server process.  The key here is that you only care about what data exists `now` where `now` is defined by the snapshot available via the materialized view.

Comment: As I understand it won´t prevent other apps to select the number and update the table while my SQL process is working. Am I right?

Comment: @user1399802 what do you mean?  In Oracle or in SQLServer?

Comment: My process runs on SQL Server, but I need to lock the Oracle table.

Comment: @user1399802 updated my answer to explain what this accomplishes.

Comment: I think that your solution doesn´t avoid that while i´m working another program selects the number, and updates the table, so, after my process finish I´m going to update the table using the same number. IE: the client number in the table is 100. My process (MP) starts, MV_client_number = 100 --> (MP) add client to some other table --> other process (OP) start --> (OP) client number =100, add client and update table to 101 --> (MP)update M.V. to 101 and finish. In this case the client number is wrong. The materialized view doesn´t help me here... or i´m missing something?

Comment: @user1399802 what are you expecting the final client number to be `100` or `101` or something else?

Comment: Ideal situation? 102, one for each new client (one from my process and one from the other process). But that I guess is possible only in a serialized transaction level, including the "select client_number".

Comment: Just for the record... may help some one... I´ve solved this using a remote call to a oracle function. The function lock/unlock the table inside the oracle environment and updates the table. This is the call: declare @i numeric exec ('BEGIN ?:= myFunc('+ @param1 +'); END; ',@i OUTPUT) at MY_LINKED_SERVER select @i Thank you all guys!

Comment: @user1399802 be careful about linked servers